# What's the difference between these two statements involving pointers arithmetic?

Tags: c, pointers, void

What is the difference between

```
 char cur_byte=*((char *)(buf+i));
```

and

```
char *b=(char *)(buf);
char cur_byte=*(b+i);
```

Assume:
buf is a pointer to void// void *buf; and
i is used as an iterator in a for loop
I found this code(the first line) in a c source code which generates rabin fingerprints and because VC2010 express reported it as an error I had to replace it with the second two lines. And I am not sure if it can do the intended purpose. Plus I would be grateful if anyone can give me a hint where to get a working C++ source code for content defined chunking and fingerprint generating.

Comment: wouldn't the first line give run time exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first statement you add an integer (`i` is an integer type, right?) to a `void*`, casting to `char*` afterwards. Pointer arithmetic with void pointers **is not defined by the C standard**, because the compiler has no way to know of how much it should increment the pointer. Some compilers, however, define `sizeof(void) == 1`. In this case, your two snippets are equivalent, which explains why this code may have worked with another compiler *(thanks Steve Jessop for pointing this)*.

What you meant in your first snippet was probably
`char cur_byte=*(((char *) buf) + i);`, the character pointed by the address located `i` characters after buf.

In the following schema, where `i==4`, `cur_byte` would be assigned the value `r`.

```
Memory: |a| |w|o|r|d
         ^       ^
        buf     buf+i
```

---

In your second statement:

```
char *b=(char *)(buf);
char cur_byte=*(b+i);
```

you first assign `buf` to `b`, and then assign the content of `b + i` to `cur_byte`. `b` has type `char*` so adding `i` will give the address `i` characters after `b`.

```
Memory: |a| |w|o|r|d|
         ^       ^
        buf         
         b      b+i
```

In the end these two statements are equivalent (except for the assignment of `b`).

Comment: but can u tell me why the first option is  an error in VC2010

Comment: "Pointer arithmetic with void pointers is not defined by the C standard" - but GCC allows it as an extension in non-pedantic modes, which is probably why the error-provoking code was written in the first place. GCC's extension in effect says that for the purposes of pointer arithmetic only, `sizeof(void) == 1`. So all of these code snippets are equivalent in GCC.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the expressions `(buf + i)` versus `(b + i)`.

`b` is of type `char*` so `(b + i)` will point to `b + sizeof(char) * i`.

`buf` could be of a different type so `(buf + i)` will point to `buf + sizeof(BUFS_TYPE) * i`.

Comment: Exactly (+1). And now after the type of `buf` has been given by John, you should extend your answer.